# How to unload a type library (.til) programmatically (preferably using IDC, but IDAPython is fine, too)?

Tags: ida, idapython, idc

TL;DR: I want to do this programmatically using either IDC or IDAPython and failed to find an option that works for me (also scoured `idc.idc`).

[image: Unloading type library from the GUI]

---

In order to explicitly load a type library I can use `add_default_til()` (formerly `LoadTil()`). However, there doesn't appear to be any counterpart to this function to unload a previously loaded type library. And that's what I am looking for.

My issue is that although `%ProgramFiles%\IDA Pro 7.7\sig\pc\autoload.cfg` does *not* list the `ntddk64_win7` and `ntapi64_win7` type libraries, they seem to get loaded implicitly *somehow*. Chances are (but I haven't found documentation to corroborate this; the only connection seems to be `autoload.cfg`) that this has to do with the following log lines:

```
Using FLIRT signature: Windows Driver Kit 7/10 64bit
Using FLIRT signature: Windows Driver Kit 7/10 64bit
Propagating type information...
Function argument information has been propagated
The initial autoanalysis has been finished.
```

Now, I'd like to unload those two and instead load `ntddk64_win10` and `ntapi64_win10` respectively (possibly re-running auto-analysis).

Alas, I haven't found a way to script this.

Bonus question: [is there something that ties the FLIRT signatures to type libraries (`.til`) *aside* from `autoload.cfg`](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/30854/245)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unload a type library you can use `del_til` function from `typeinf.hpp`.

Usage with IDAPython:

```
import ida_typeinf

ida_typeinf.add_til("ntapi64_win7", ida_typeinf.ADDTIL_DEFAULT) # load a til file
ida_typeinf.del_til("ntapi64_win7") # unload a til file
```

Comment: Guess I won't get around using IDAPython after all  ... thanks and welcome to RE.SE.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why you are using IDC in this case, but I want to remind you that there is an `exec_python` function in `idc.idc`, maybe that will help :)

Comment: so something like `exec_python("import ida_typeinf;ida_typeinf.del_til('ntapi64_win7');ida_typeinf.add_til('ntapi64_win10', ida_typeinf.ADDTIL_DEFAULT)")` would work (but it looks terrible)