# Auto-loaded type information and relationship between .til and .sig: how to find links and how to change them (config)?

Tags: ida

NB: most of my targets are PE files for `pc`, so I'll stick with that for the question. But I suppose the principle holds also for the related directories, like `$IDADIR/sig/arm`.

Let's say I load a PE file, which happens to be a 64-bit Windows driver. I may then see in the Output pane (redacted for brevity):

```
IDA is analysing the input file...
You may start to explore the input file right now.
...
Using FLIRT signature: Windows Driver Kit 7/10 64bit
Propagating type information...
```

Now "Windows Driver Kit 7/10 64bit" corresponds to `$IDADIR/sig/pc/ms64wdk.sig` (found with `dumpsig`). Fair enough. I also know that `$IDADIR/sig/pc/autoload.cfg` governs what type information library (`.til`) file gets loaded based on the loading of a signature.

Alas, there is no entry that maps the aforementioned `$IDADIR/sig/pc/ms64wdk.sig` to `ntddk64_win7` and `ntapi64_win7`. Yet, when I use <kbd>Produce file</kbd> -> <kbd>Dump database to IDC file...</kbd> the resulting `.idc` file has the following calls among its first actions (again redacted for brevity):

```
#define UNLOADED_FILE   1
#include <idc.idc>

static main(void) {
    // ...
    GenInfo();            // various settings
    // ...
}

static GenInfo(void) {

    // ...
    add_default_til("ntddk64_win7");
    add_default_til("ntapi64_win7");
}
```

#### Questions:

- How does IDA make the connection between the FLIRT (`.sig`) and the `.til` here? (Apparently `$IDADIR/sig/pc/autoload.cfg` has no bearing.)
- Given there are also other `.til` files like `ntddk64_win10.til`, `ntapi64_win10.til`:

  - How can I configure IDA to load those instead of the somehow implicit `ntddk64_win7` and `ntapi64_win7` respectively?
  - Assuming I can't override the behavior or have an existing IDB which had the implicit `ntddk64_win7` and `ntapi64_win7` applied: If I now use `add_default_til("ntddk64_win10")` and `add_default_til("ntapi64_win10")` (no matter whether IDC or IDAPython) will this adversely affect existing usage of type information (e.g. enums which were imported from standard enums)? How does it affect existing usage?
- What is the relation between the `ntddk64.til` and, say, `ntddk64_vista.til`, `ntddk64_win7.til`, `ntddk64_win8.til`, `ntddk64_win81.til` and `ntddk64_win10.til`? Is `ntddk64.til` the superset? Some subset?

PS: Pointers to official documentation very much welcome.

Comment: Meanwhile I noticed, that a bunch of those names are hardcoded in some of the loaders, processors and plugins that come with IDA, as well as the `ida.dll` and `ida64.dll`. So there's clearly more than `autoload.cfg` at work here.